# French representations of functions

Tags: spacing, arrays

In France (probably in many other countries, too), functions are usually represented like this:
[image]

So, I tried to create a command `\fct` and here is a MWE:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt]{article}

\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{newtxtext}
\usepackage[frenchmath]{newtxmath}

\DeclarePairedDelimiterX{\intoo}[2]{]}{[}{{#1}\,{,}\,{#2}}

\newcommand*{\fct}[5]%
{\begin{array}[t]{@{}c@{}c@{}c@{}c}
       #1 \colon & #2 &  \; \longrightarrow & \; #3 \cr & #4 & \;\longmapsto & \; #5 
      \end{array}}
                 
\begin{document}
  $f\colon\intoo{-1}{1}\longrightarrow\varmathbb{\R}$  
  
  $\fct{f}{\intoo{-1}{1}}{\varmathbb{R}}{x}{\dfrac{1}{\sqrt{1-x^2}}}$
\end{document}
```

In my command `\fct` , the parameters #1 to #4 have to be centered and I want:

- the space between the name of the function and the `\colon`
- the space between the interval and the arrow

be exactly the same as in `f:\colon\intoo{-1}{1}\longrightarrow\varmathbb{R}`. That's why I typed the first line in my MWE: to see if the alignment is correct. It seems to be fine but I wonder if I did this in the right way. I had to add thickspaces in my array before and after my arrow.
So maybe there is a better (simplier?) way to do this. And I am also not sure my command will work in all circumstances (I won't need it in scriptscriptstyle but maybe in scripstyle)

Comment: Why do you suppress inter-column space with `@{}` and then you re-add it?

Comment: You mean before and after the arrow? Beacause I don’t know the exact value of inter-column space

Comment: If you use `@{\;}` you have `\;` as intercolumn space --- and it's cleaner because you use it just in one place.

Comment: @Rmano: intercolumn space is always the same, but not the space between math operators, relations, ...

Comment: @user187802 Yes --- I was suggesting just what you implemented ;-)

Answer (score 6):

I prefer to draw this kind of diagram with `tikz-cd` package. I have written the open interval using `\DeclarePairedDelimiter` from `mathtools`[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}
\DeclarePairedDelimiter{\open}{]}{[}
\newcommand{\fct}[5]{
  \begin{tikzcd}[row sep=tiny,ampersand replacement=\&]
      #1\colon \&[-3em] #2\ar[r] \& #3\\
               \& #4\ar[mapsto,r] \& #5
    \end{tikzcd}
}
\begin{document}
\begin{center}
  \fct{f}{A}{B}{a}{b} \qquad
  \fct{f}{\open{-1,1}}{B}{x}{y}
\end{center}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 5):

```
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt]{article}

\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{newtxtext}
\usepackage[frenchmath]{newtxmath}

\DeclarePairedDelimiterX{\intoo}[2]{]}{[}{{#1}\,{,}\,{#2}}

\newcommand*\fct[5]%
{\begin{array}[t]{@{} 
   l% name
   @{\,:\:} % colon 
   l% interval 
   @{\:} 
   l%  arrow
   @{\,} 
   l% set 
 }
       #1 & #2 & \longrightarrow & \varmathbb{#3}\\
       \multicolumn{2}{r}{#4} & \mapsto & #5   
  \end{array}}
                 
\begin{document}
  $f\colon\intoo{-1}{1}\longrightarrow\varmathbb{\R}$  
  
  $\fct{f}%
      {\intoo{-1}{1}}%
      {R}%
      {x}%
      {\dfrac{1}{\sqrt{1-x^2}}}$
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Forgot to use `\longmapsto` ...

Comment: Thank you. It’s not exactly what I want because the x and the R are not centered. And the intervals on the two lines are not perfectly aligned (the second is more on the left)